# Align two set of checkboxes side by side

Tags: html, css, checkbox

Hi I'm trying to align two set of checkboxes in form side by side and make the checkboxes align nicely but everytime I get the checkboxes side by side the one on the right will be mess up depend on the text size on the left

so I'm wondering if there is a way

here is the code

UPDATE THE BROKEN CODE.

http://jsfiddle.net/Ysf7t/1/

Comment: Can you post a broken example? That code renders fine for me.

Comment: What are you trying to do. Your example doesn't have any label elements which are required to be valid HTML (not to mention accessibility). You;ll want to make sure everything is in there prior to styling so you don't run into the issue again later.

Comment: You'll need to either wrap the text in an element, in order to assign it a width (to allow for lining up the subsequent elements) or use JavaScript, essentially, to do the same. Which would you prefer?

Comment: You could consider using a table to align form elements and take out the table borders. Tables are commonly used to align form elements.

Comment: @DavidThomas I'm not allow to have any javascript at this point because it needs to be plain CSS+HTML

Comment: 'Allowed' by what criteria? is this a [tag:homework] question, or is it a different type of constraint?

Comment: @DavidThomas not really a homework but it's what someone ask me to help him create a page for his business and he asks not to have any javascript because of some reason.

Comment: There are multiple ways to properly label form fields which is why the <label> element isn't required for validation. It is still invalid markup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way would be to give the names (i.e. "Soccer", "Mercedes", etc.) a fixed width through CSS.

Basically something like this:

```
<h1>Sports</h1>

<div>
    <input type='checkbox' name='system_type17' value='2' />
    <input type="checkbox" name="system_type3" value="5" />
    <span style="width:100px;display:inline-block;">Soccer</span>
    <input type='checkbox' name='system_type17' value='2' />
    <input type="checkbox" name="system_type3" value="5" />
    <span style="width:100px;display:inline-block;">Mercedes</span>
</div>           
<div>
    <input type='checkbox' name='system_type18' value='3' />
    <input type='checkbox' name='system_type4' value='4' />
    <span style="width:100px;display:inline-block;">Mercedes</span>
    <input type="checkbox" name="system_type7" value="2" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="system_type8" value="3" />
    <span style="width:100px;display:inline-block;">Mercedes</span>
</div>
```

Of course, ideally, the CSS shouldn't be inline.  But I hope you get what I mean.

Comment: I'm accepting your solution but I used margin-left instead of width in this case. :)

Comment: If it works for you, fine, but margin-left does something different than width.  Width defines a fixed width (lets say 100px), so all text has the same space to occupy (BMW, the same as Mercedes).  With margin-left, you only give the exact same left margin (lets say 20px) to the text, no matter how long the text is.  So BMW will be its original width PLUS 20px and Mercedes will be its original width PLUS 20px.

Comment: well I didn't apply the class to the text that's why it works for me in this case, is like I just use &nbsp; but instead I use margin to the left so I can get exactly position I want for the checkboxes to be appear.